# Flume Custom HTTPSourceHandler GZipped File

Tags: java, flume, flume-ng

I am trying to create a custom Flume HTTPSourceHandler that handles the contents of a file that is sent in the POST body of an HTTP request, and the payload of that post will be gzipped.

I am new to Flume, and struggling to understand how to return the contents of this GZip file (or any data for that matter) as Flume events.

Here is some incomplete code I am working on.  The main goal right now is to simply print console of file to console.

Any tips, examples, etc. would be very helpful.

```
import org.apache.flume.Event;
import org.apache.flume.source.http.HTTPSourceHandler;
import org.apache.http.HttpHeaders;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream;

public class HttpGzipHandler extends HTTPSourceHandler{

    public HttpGzipHandler(){

    }

    public List<Event> getEvents(HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
        boolean isGzipped = request.getHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_ENCODING) != null
                && request.getHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_ENCODING).contains("gzip");
        GZIPInputStream gzipInputStream = new GZIPInputStream(request.getInputStream());

        List<Event> eventList = new ArrayList<Event>(0);


        //TODO: Return the Events
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have a look on a [custom Http handler](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-cygnus/blob/master/src/main/java/com/telefonica/iot/cygnus/handlers/OrionRestHandler.java) I've developed for a tool named Cygnus, as an inspiration. I think the important part for you will be the code where the event is created and emitted:

```
// create the appropiate headers
Map<String, String> eventHeaders = new HashMap<String, String>();
eventHeaders.put(..., ...);

// create the event list containing only one event
ArrayList<Event> eventList = new ArrayList<Event>();
Event event = EventBuilder.withBody(data.getBytes(), eventHeaders);
eventList.add(event);

return eventList;
```